# problem sending bytes through an AS3 Socket to my FTP site

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, ftp, jpeg

I have some as3 code which successfully opens 2 socket connections to my FTP server. One for commands and one for data. I am using the STOR command to create a file on the FTP server and then sending an encoded jpeg from a byteArray using writeBytes. I then flush the data socket and close it successfully.

All of this appears to be fine apart from the fact that the byteArray is 826 bytes long and I end up with a file which is only 817 bytes on the ftp server which not surprisingly isn't recognised as a jpeg.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you missing bytes at the beginning or end of the JPEG file?

Comment: near the beginning. I just downloaded a hex viewer and the header seems corrupted. looking at the byteArray I think it may be ASCII/BINARY problem as the 4th and 5th byte should be 0D 0A which is going astray.

Comment: Sorry guys - I had mistyped the TYPE command and it was defaulting to ASCII rather than binary !!!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the FTP protocol, but are you configuring the transfer to use "binary mode" if such exists (I know it does in some clients)? 0x0D 0x0A is a Windows newline sequence (CRLF) and I wouldn't expect that to be in a JPEG header.

Comment: thanks Richard - the problem was in the mode setting which should have been TYPE I to switch to binary mode and had a typo which defaulted it back to ASCII.

Comment: Oh, and yes I was trying lots of things so the OD OA was part of a PNG header. Problem solved now :)

Comment: you should post the answer for future reference and mark it as answered in a few days.  don't delete the question, it's a good one.

Comment: Don't forget to post and accept the real answer..

Comment: Post and accept your answer Kevin!

Comment: -1 for not posting his answer

Answer (score 3):

**Please do not +1 this answer, nor mark it as correct.  I am only posting the comment and answer from @richarddolsson and @Kevin.  Go to the comments and add plusses there.  I am doing this because this is showing up as "unaswered" in the searches.**

@richarddolsson - Configure the transfer to use "binary mode" if such exists (I know it does in some clients). 0x0D 0x0A is a Windows newline sequence (CRLF) and I wouldn't expect that to be in a JPEG header.

@Kevin - The problem was in the mode setting which should have been TYPE I to switch to binary mode and had a typo which defaulted it back to ASCII.